# A Right Circular Cone with Height H and Base Radius R

Tags: calculus

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8N7C.png)

[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFd7h.png)

Hi I am wondering how this works? I am confused as to what they are doing in this problem. I've tried so many times my brain hurts already.

Picture 1 shows the example video, and picture 2 shows my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: think of the cone as a stack of very thin disks (ultimately *dh* tall), with the largest diameter at the bottom and the smallest at the top.  Now, figure out how to calculate the volume of each disk and, using calculus, sum them up.

Comment: Can you give me more hints...I am so stuck on these problems. I think I need a personal tutor. DX

Comment: sure.  If you made the cone approximation as I described, tell me what the radius is of the disk at height h